# The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. upon clicking Personalize button of any component

Tags: xconnect, personalization

I am getting the below error on clicking Personalize button of any component in production sitecore instance which is working fine in other environments. We are using Sitecore 9 and SXA. I have attached the screenshot too. Not able to find the reason.

[image]

Comment: can you check connection strings to reporting database?

Comment: I doubt this is SXA related...

Comment: There is no entry for reporting database in connection strings. Instead, there is an entry for reporting.apikey

Answer (score 2):

This happens when reporting api keys are not configured properly. It should be configured both in CM instance and reporting server.

If the authentication keys do not match, the server responds with a 403 (Forbidden) status code.

Please do read below links for more details:-

Configure security keys on servers in a scaled environment https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/configuring_servers/configuring_servers/configure_security_keys_on_servers_in_a_scaled_environment

Configure a Reporting Service server
https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/server-role-configuration-reference/core-roles/reporting-service/index.html

Configure reporting API key
https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/server-role-configuration-reference/core-roles/reporting-service/configure-reporting-api-key.html

Comment: Our site is hosted in Azure (PaaS) and there is no entry for reporting database in connectionstrings.config file. Instead, there is an entry for reporting.apikey. Please let me know whether the problem is due to not having entry related to reporting database. If not, how can i validate the api keys in azure model

Comment: @ManideepYechuri - We are facing the same issue. Did you find any solution to the problem? if yes please share.